# The tangent at the point $P(x_0,y_0)$ to the parabola $y^2=4ax$ meets the parabola $y^2=4a(x+b)$ at Q and R,

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Problem :

The tangent at the point $P(x_0,y_0)$ to the parabola $y^2=4ax$ meets the parabola $y^2=4a(x+b)$ at $Q$ and $R$, the coordinates the mid point of $QR$ are ?

Solution :

Tangent from a point $P(x_0,y_0)$ to the parabola $y^2=4ax$ is $yy_0 =2a(x+x_0)$

Request you to please suggest how to approach this problem further thanks.

Comment: I think you just have to solve the tangent equation and the other parabola $y^2=4a(x+b)$

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $ y =2a(x+x_0)/y_0$ in the parabola $y^2=4a(x+b)$ then solve for x.

We will get two values for x now plug these values in the tangent equation to get y values. You will get the points.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you put $2ax = yy_0-2ax_0$ in to $y^2=4ax+4ab$ you get $$y^2-2y_0y+4ax_0-4ab =0$$

So if $M(x_M,y_M)$ is a midpoint for $PQ$ we get, using Vieta formula:  $$y_M={1\over 2}(y_1+y_2)={1\over 2}2y_0 = y_0$$ so $$x_M= {y_0^2-2ax_0\over 2a}$$